# how can i debug variable value in __init__.py

Tags: python, django, django-registration

New to python and django .i want to understand the code of django-registration module for this i want to debug the value in code.
So i m stuck here that

```
i = path.rfind('.')
    module, attr = path[:i], path[i+1:]

print {i}
#or
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

my registration form is not showing and gives error .

```
IndentationError at /accounts/register/
unexpected indent (__init__.py, line 19)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://50.56.78.125:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: IndentationError
Exception Value:    
unexpected indent (__init__.py, line 19)
```

How can i debug or see the value of i .

This is the code :

```
i = path.rfind('.')
    module, attr = path[:i], path[i+1:]
    try:
        mod = import_module(module)
    except ImportError, e:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured('Error loading registration backend %s: "%s"' % (module, e))
    try:
        backend_class = getattr(mod, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured('Module "%s" does not define a registration backend named "%s"' % (module, attr))
    return backend_class()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentations matter a lot in python, and as the error suggests, you have an indentation problem. You should only indent when creating a new block of code, for example after `if`, `for` or `while` statements.

Just remove the whitespaces before `module`:

```
i = path.rfind('.')
module, attr = path[:i], path[i+1:]

print i
#or
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: tried but still error ? updated the code in question please give print statement in that . , is print statement will come in putty from where i am running the server ?

Comment: worked changed my notepad ++ setting to tab replace  by space,thanks